# On elementary proof of Stokes' theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surface-integrals, stokes-theorem

I have looked at several elementary proofs (i.e., using only basic calculus, and not using differential form or manifold) of Stokes' theorem in books and Wikipedia, and all seem to use the fact that the mixed second partials of the parametrization of the surface are equal ($\psi_{uv}=\psi_{vu}$). But the statement of Stokes' theorem assumes that the surface is smooth, which only requires $C^1$ parametrization (and nonvanishing Jacobian). Is it possible that in Stokes' theorem, we need that the surface is $C^2$, not $C^1$ ?

Comment: I believe that $C^2$ is in fact required, even with differential forms and pullbacks. Where are you seeing a careful treatment that says $C^1$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem#Proof) and Petrovic's Advanced Calculus, p. 450.

Comment: I don’t see any specification in Wiki of what “smooth” means. They do specify that the vector field is $C^1$, which is correct. I have no access to Petrovic and know nothing about it.

Comment: I think I saw the $C^1$-surface proof in Kaplan's Advanced Calculus, too, although the book is in library and has no online access. It had the same error of using the mixed derivative theorem.

Comment: Peter Lax's Multivariable Calculus with Application also has the $C^1$-surface proof using mixed derivative test, on p.356.

Comment: Even Stewart and Thomas calculus states Stokes' theorem with $C^1$ surface.

Comment: It is far from elementary, but you can deduce the $C^1$ case by uniformly approximating by $C^2$ functions. Indeed, the theorem holds more generally if one ventures into the realm of currents. See DeRham’s book and books on geometric measure theory. Calculus books are out of their depth here.